# Elaborate css for a background image gradient

Tags: css, image, gradient

I folks.  This might be more of a design question but I thought I'd give it a whirl in case someone had some masterful CSS techniques I could use. If not, I'll brace myself for the onslaught of down-voting and nay saying!

You can see the logo holder here has a background image with a nice gradient to the right, and is obviously semi-transparent. My client is looking for a gradient at the top and right side.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

[alt text http://www.linkhostmedia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Screen-shot-2010-01-28-at-4.31.45-PM.png](http://www.linkhostmedia.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Screen-shot-2010-01-28-at-4.31.45-PM.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be to use a partially-transparent image as the background-image for the container-div.

```
#container_div {background: transparent url(path/to/image.png) bottom right no-repeat; }
```

Comment: You see the problem I'm facing though right?  on the left at the top it's not a big deal to fade upward. There are a few ways you can tackle that.  But as you get closer to the right, blending it up AND right gets tricky.  CSS asside, I don't even know how to accomplish this from a design standpoint.

Comment: Um, no; I don't think I do. From your comment I'm thinking that you want a gradient that runs from the bottom right corner? Just create an image with alpha-channel transparency and position it with css. Am I missing something? This doesn't *seem* hard... =/

Comment: @jeerose: Well from the graphics standpoint youre going to have to make a an opacity mask on the left->right fade itself. thats actually pretty easy to accomplish in Fireworks, Photoshop or Illustrator. Now it looks to me like this thing can be a static width and also possibly a static height so im not sure what is giving you problems... Does adding that gradient forbid a background-repeat in a direction you need or something?

Comment: It's pretty easy in the GIMP, too, for what it's worth.

Comment: @prodigistalson, I don't know why I didn't think of that before but your "opacity mask" triggered it for me.  I applied a gradient mask to the existing fade from top to bottom.  Worked like a charm.  Thank-you!